# GET request doesn't work when returned List<> contains items

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, long-polling

I'm running into a strange problem while working on a .NET REST application. I can make all sorts of requests just fine, but this one long-polling-GET-interruption request only succeeds if the returned List is empty. To illustrate:

```
public async Task<List<Person>> UpdateRequest()
{
    try
    {
        await LongPolling(10000);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Long polling GET was cancelled.");
        var fooList = new List<Person>();
        fooList.Add(new Person("tim", "bar")); // <- adding this line breaks the request

        return fooList;
    }

    return null; //Timeout, aka nothing happened
}
```

When the `.Add()` line is not there, calling `mysite.com/update` (and subsequent interrupting of the long GET) returns

```
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/stuff" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

which is expected, but when the `List` contains items,  I get an instant "Could not get a response". The Console.Writeline is printed. Am I misunderstanding the way `List` works in C#? Or maybe I'm going wrong with the return type `Task<List<Person>>`?

Edit: tried it with a normal array: `Person[0]` is the only thing that works, bigger arrays "Could not get a response" regardless if there's items in them.

Comment: You should never return `null` if the result is an collection. Rather return an empty list. Then it won't break iterators etc. `return new List<Person>()` or create a static `EmptyPersonList`

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but true :)

Comment: @Fildor Yes. The GET request is held and returns a "timeout" (null in this case, will change) if the long polling does not get interrupted.

Comment: @Fildor yes, his idea is to cancel the task when items are received within the timeout and a full response can be given else the operation has a timeout and not results are present. The code isn't fully complete, that's why it isn't very clear.

Comment: Dough, ok. I need to grab a coffee ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the culprit was not `Task<>`. Non-async methods (with `List<Person>` as return type) had the same problem. The client simply does not know how to map a non-empty list of custom objects to a response, which is understandable in hindsight.

I ended up explicitly mapping the `List` to XML inside the `UpdateRequest()` method, resulting in `Task<XElement>` being the new return type.